# populate HTML table with JQuery AJAX using JSON formatted data

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am new here and newbie learner. I've checked some similar questions like this but could not get them to work. 
What I am trying to achieve is, querying my database, retrieve list of accounts, then jquery function sends a query to ajaxtest2.php file for each of the account to retrieve account information and shows it in a html table.

Main problem is, table is populating with information of the last account in the database instead of all accounts.

I am getting this output at the moment:

```
`3459   1459    3459    1459`
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank yoU :)

```
 include_once('database.php');

$sql1 = "select * from account ";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);


while ($arr1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    $var = $arr1["account_no"];
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {



        $(window).load(function() {

        var numValue = <?php echo $var; ?>;
    $.getJSON("ajaxtest2.php", {number: numValue}, function(data){

    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(data, function () {
    trHTML += '<td>' + data.bal + '</td><td>' + data.eq + '</td>';
    });
    $('#location').append(trHTML);
    });
    }); `
});
</script>
<table id="location" border='1'>
</table>

<?php

}
```

The below is the response from ajaxtest2.php

```
echo json_encode(array("bal" => "$balance", "eq" => "$equity")); 
?>
```

Comment: can you show us the full ajaxtest2.php code?

Comment: <?php
include 'data/mt.php';
$number = $_GET["number"]);
if ($number > 0){
$data = array('command' => 'user_data_get', 'data' => array( 'login' => $number )  );   
       }
 $result = request_send ($data);
 $balance = $result['data']['balance'];
 $equity= $result['data']['equity'];
 echo json_encode(array("bal" => "$balance", "eq" => "$equity")); 
 
?>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have table rows when you generate the cells.

```
trHTML += '<tr><td>' + data.bal + '</td><td>' + data.eq + '</td></tr>';
```

Else your cells will always append to the right of the previous cell without changing rows

Also, the your code could all be done using PHP only (no js)

### Here's how:

```
<?php
include_once('database.php');

$sql1 = "select * from account ";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1);
?>

<table id="location" border='1'>
    <?php
    while ($arr1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $var = $arr1["account_no"];

        //your ajaxtest2.php functionnalities go here
        //let's say $accBalance and $accEquity contain the information you wanted about that specific row

        echo '<tr><td>'.$accBalance.'</td><td>'.$accEquity.'</td></tr>';
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

And there you have your populated table using database values without using JS.

Hoped it helped!

Comment: Thank you Proto.  The database query only retrieves the list of account numbers, nothing else. For each of the account number from database, it sends a request to our API host which is located at ajaxtest2.php and retrieves account balance, equity etc. This is the reason we need JS.    So, the problem still continues. It only retrieves data for last account number in the database. The response from ajaxtest2.php is mentioned in my earlier comment. Will be great if you have any idea.